# viewing rows and/or rowcounts between activities (similar to ssis data viewer)

Tags: ssis, azure-data-factory

Does azure data factory have a built in way of viewing the records as they pass or have passed through the data flow activities?

Or, at the very least, view row counts of what was inserted, updated, deleted, upserted at the sink?

Answer (score 0):

From the monitoring view in ADF at run time and from the data preview tab at design time.

Monitoring view runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-monitoring

[image]

Data Preview design-time view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-debug-mode#data-preview

Comment: thanks. I have viewed this but i cant see what is being updated vs inserted vs deleted. With SSIS i would just use a data viewer. what i need to know is if i can see this information in Azure data factory without adding additional components?

Comment: Yes, update, delete, insert, upsert, are performed using the Alter Row transformation. The debug view provides that feedback: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row#view-policies-in-data-preview